# Python Django multiple lines form

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

I am new to Django and trying to build a form within the page. The form has multiple fields and all the fields are displayed in the same line on the page. I am using the following code in the template:

```
 <form action='' method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
```

I want a form that each field appears in a different line. Is there a way to do this from the django framework or css?

thanks!

Comment: Since you added the bootstrap-4 tag, you may find this [3rd-party app](https://django-bootstrap4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
```

The `as_p` stands for *as paragraph*, which is what you want for multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can display the content of a form:

As paragraphs...

`{{ form.as_p }}`

...tables...

`{{ form.as_table }}`

...or unordered list.

`{{ form.as_ul }}`